# Url rewrite rule for redirecting to specific page in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, url-routing

ASP.NET 4.5 Webforms website

I have two domains:

- company.com
- company.co.ca

Both pointing to the same site and the default document is set to login.aspx.

When someone goes to company.co.ca, I check the Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] in the login.aspx.cs and redirect users to **company.co.ca/ca/login.aspx**

I thought I can use the url rewrite and have this rule in my web.config but it doesn't redirect but stays on the main login.aspx.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CA HomePage" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="company.co.ca/login.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="company.co.ca/ca/login.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

We are planning to add one more domain and so I don't want to do a manual check in login.aspx.cs and redirect and want to find a more general best way.

Answer (score 0):

You check for the host like this with IIS rewrites:

```
<rule name="CA HomePage" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^login.aspx$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^company.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://company.co.ca/ca/login.aspx" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I did try but behaved the same. Any idea why the one I have above won't work?